# How Disable Auto-focus of a webcam using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I am trying to calibrate two cameras but my problem is the auto-focus. Im using the webcam logitech c920. Anyone knows a way to disable the auto-focus feature??  Im using C++ and opencv 2.4.9 in osx system.

Comment: Somehow one has to bear in mind, that when you stop auto-focus you will be left with whatever perfect or random focus distance for your needs that you had at that moment. So you may obviously sometimes want to set the focus manually after that.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) // Generate camera object
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0) // turn the autofocus off
```

You can find more information on how to set some properties at these links.

The VideoCapture class

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html

The VideoCapture properties

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d

Comment: Doesn`t work, I think is for opencv version. I have opencv 2.4.9.

Comment: You can try the Logitech Webcam Software.

http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920/downloads

If it does not work, you can try downloading other similar software, I have seen someone controlling the focus of their webcam using a software while streaming to OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Try v4l-utils:

1. Install: `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`
2. Find your device `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`
3. Replace *video0* with output from the previous command and disable autofocus with:
   `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=focus_auto=0`